# Why do codes work in the onCreate() instead of onResume()

Tags: java, android

I'm like an intermediate in android programming. I decided to take a deep dive into the Activity lifecycle methods and I realised something, like why do methods Toasts.show() and many other methods get called again when the activity is resumed. If the methods are in the onCreate so why then if you like go to another activity and return it will still give you a Toast message. Let me give an example.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

{Your Initialization go here }


 //Toas message 
 Toast.makeText(code).show();
 }
 }
```

So imagine you leaving this activity for another one and then coming back... why does it still show the Toast message. Because since the lifecycle is
OnCreate
onResume
onStart
onPause
onstop
onDestroy

And when you come back to your MainActivity it calls the
onResume
onStart.
So if onCreate is not called...So how does the Toast message show.
Please someone should help me answer this I've searched all day but couldn't find answers.

Comment: It may or may be not called ... if Toast from `onCreate` is shown then `onCreate` was called ... it's not clear how did you check that `onCreate` was not called and toast was show FROM THE `onCreate` ...

Answer (score 1):

accoording to lifecycle of activity https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle, if there is no memory engouh the app process will kill, so when you back to your activity on created will call another time.

the image below for clarification:
[image]

Comment: Is the onCreate always running ?

Comment: No, only when the system the process becuase the memory, check from Profiler for memory. @VictorAnyichie

Answer (score 0):

When your activity goes in the background, and memory is required for other apps. It is possible that the system frees up space even though your activity is in the background with ONPAUSED state. and now if you navigate to your activity, since the saved instance is removed due to memory requirements. instead of ONRESUME, ONSTART is called. you can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
and see this image for better understanding: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/images/activity_lifecycle.png

This uncertainty is one of the reasons why we now mostly use view models for a sizeable app.